# Update statistics maintenance plan trying to update a table statistics which doesn't exists in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with the scenario:

> Failed:(-1073548784) Executing the query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[ABC] 
>   WITH FULLSCAN..." failed with the following error: 
>   "Table 'ABC' does not exist.". 
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>    "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

I found there is no table or view in all databases with the name ABC
here I don't know why maintenance plan trying to update the one which not exist currently

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Not sure what part of that error message isn't clear. And if your maintenance plan is trying to do this automatically I would ask what your maintenance plan is doing. Have you considered creating a sql job yourself instead of using the maintenance plans?

Comment: Hi Sean,
I am clear with the error message.
My maintenance plan created to update all statistics for all databases.
Here my maintenance plan getting failed for updating the statistics of the non existing(May be dropped) one.
How can i make to run the maintenance plan successfully

Comment: I would suggest not using a maintenance plan. Create a sql job that does what you need it to do instead. It is pretty challenging for me to help with your maintenance plan because I have no idea how you have created it.

Comment: How did you verify there was no table or view ABC? By looking in object explorer or looking at sys.tables, etc?

Comment: Thanks Sean
Here I have to make to Maintenance plan to run.
Maintenance created with two steps
1.Rebuilding indexes--it was running smoothly(No issues)
2. Update statistics--here is the problem

Comment: Hi Chao
i tried in both  Object explorer and command line but didn't found ABC either in table or in View
Please help